# How to make on click listener as property of activity?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make my click events as properties on my activity. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but as new to Android I'm borrowing what I know from C# or JavaScript. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView topTextView;
    Button counterButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init view elements
        topTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        counterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Init element events
        counterButton.setOnClickListener(onCounterButtonClick);
    }

    private OnClickListener onCounterButtonClick(final MainActivity activity) {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, 
                    "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                topTextView.setText("Updated from button");
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: THis won't work like that at all.  First off, Java doesn't have properties.  Secondly, this isn't legal Java-  you can't pass a function A  parameter.  And to a java user it just looks weird-  you either store the lick listener as a variable, or you pass it in as an anonymous class directly.  You wouldn't make a function to return it.

Comment: obvious answer is yes, would it only be because this code does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare the listener as a field of the class instead.

```
private OnClickListener onCounterButtonClick  = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    };
}
```

And use it as the parameter.

Comment: Ah nice! Extensible too because now I can subclass and override that field if needed.

Answer (score 1):

exactly i don't now if it's this that you want. But Android has other way to define the actions in a Button for example:
In your `activity.xml` define the Button property `onClick=myFunction` then in your `Activity.java` write the method like this:

activity.xml

```
....
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_1"
    android:onClick="myFunction"
    android:text="@string/Button_1" />
....
```

Activity.java

```
public void myFunction(View v) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView topTextView;
    Button counterButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init view elements
        topTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        counterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Init element events
        counterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               if(view.getId == R.id.button1){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, 
                    "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                topTextView.setText("Updated from button");
                }
           }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, very creative!

Comment: I ended up using this in another part of my app.. I just realized you borrowed the concept from iOS delegates and worked well for passing methods as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `View.OnClickListener()` anonymous inner class.

```
counterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, 
                "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Init view elements
        topTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        counterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Init element events
        counterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Button was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                topTextView.setText("Updated from button");
            }
        });
    }
```

You can set the `onClickListener` directly also, and instead of passing the activity of parameter, you can use the `getApplicationContext()` function to get the context.